# Find illuminance value of an image taken from a camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, camera, rgb

I got an application that should calculate the illuminance of an given photo.

My problem is: `i can't find a way to calculate this illuminance index (in lux)`

i can get `luminosity` with this code:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
unsigned char* pixels = [image rgbaPixels];
double totalLuminance = 0.0;
for(int p=0;p<image.size.width*image.size.height*4;p+=4) {
  totalLuminance += pixels[p]*0.299 + pixels[p+1]*0.587 + pixels[p+2]*0.114;
}
totalLuminance /= (image.size.width*image.size.height);
totalLuminance /= 255.0;
NSLog(@"Image.png = %f",totalLuminance);
```

[Source](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera)

but the results are between `0 and 1`, witch i don't think i can use to calculate `illuminance` in `lux`

looking for an answer on stack overflow i found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720635/839049 witch gave me a direction, but i don't know how to proceed because i don't know what to do with exposure.

> .. you can just ignore the pixel data and just use the exposure information as a light meter. ...

how? does anyone know how do i do that?
or there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the exposure value from the Exif data, then the total scene illuminance can be calculated as

```
pow(2, Exposure)*(0.3 * Calibration);
```

where Calibration, unfortunately, depends on the physical characteristics of the scene you're imaging. If you have a lot of dark, low-reflectivity objects, then the constant will have to be set higher.

Usually the Exposure works out so that the average illuminance you get from your formula, i.e., the sum of all your Y values divided by the number of pixels, is around 0.5 (but that depends on the camera's "brain": some cameras divide the scene in "zones" and apply different weights to each zone, e.g. they try to get 0.5 in the central area even if this means darkening the edges; the latest cameras integrate the contrast values, so as to capture the most details from what they deduce to be the "zone of interest").

This means that your image will always be "scaled", unless you somehow instruct the camera to take pictures at a fixed speed and stop setting, without compensating in any way. If you do, you will be able to use the average pixel luminance to determine total apparent illuminance.

You will always have to calibrate your results with a known meter, though.